# Create SVN branch from specific Tag and merge to trunk

Tags: svn, tags, branch

recently we moved to svn.

I have two questions here,

1. we had release and created tag TAG1.
   after a week there was a production issue and prod code base is TAG1, later on trunk we made several changes that we don't want to push to production, so the best way is here take code from TAG1 and do change, we have exported data from tag but not able to commit and we don't want to commit to that tag,  need a separate branch after the release make another tag(TAG2) based on this branch then finally merge to Trunk. Merge to Trunk is not an issue. the issue is here how to create a branch from Tag based code and do commit changes?
2. We have releases for every two months, all these changes made directly on trunk, after the release we create a TAG and continues for next release.
   other end, we are going to start a new project XYZ that will release at year end(date not yet decided), here, this branch needs to create from previous TAG not from trunk because already made some changes on trunk for up coming release, how we we can achieve it?.

Thanks
KV

Answer (score 19):

```
svn copy your.repo.URL/tags/your-tag-name your.repo.URL/branches/your-new-branch-name -m "message"
```

then to work on it

```
svn checkout your.repo.URL/branches/your-new-branch-name
```

Answer (score 6):

branches and tags are the same thing: a cheap copy from one URL and version to another URL.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.copy for the reference of the copy command. What you just need is:

```
svn copy http://svn.foo.com/project/tags/TAG1 http://svn.foo.com/project/branches/maintenance-TAG1
```

Comment: thanks guys for quick respond. now I have below error "svn could not use external editor to fetch log message consider setting the $svn_editor environment", If I try with -m "message" gets below error svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output

Comment: How did you create the tag? Do the same for the branch, but with the appropriate URLs. I don't know what youir pre-commit hook does.

Comment: For the error:"svn could not use external editor to fetch log message consider setting the $svn_editor environment" -->do 2 commands: 1) bash
2)export SVN_EDITOR=nano

Comment: Alternative fix for the external editor issue: supply the commit message yourself using -m "creating maintenance-TAG1"