# How we can checkout the particular codebase(or data) of previous version in svn and ClearCase

Tags: svn, clearcase

I am going through the version tools and Here I learned that we can tag our changes and can secure our old data in repository and can reuse in future. So my question is how we can checkout the codebase of some old verison:

Say, I have the single branch "abc_01.00" which is used by all developers, as the time goes, I have applied below verison on **same branch**:

1. 00.00.01 (for 2012 year)
2. 00.00.02 (for 2013 year)
3. 00.00.03 (for 2014 year)

Now, there is some urgent requirement and I want to checkout the codebase for year 2012 against "00.00.01" tag. So how I can do this as branch is same for all three version in svn or ClearCase.

Comment: SVN and ClearCase are *very* different version control systems. Which are you actually asking about? Or do you really need the answer for both systems?

Comment: @Ben I want to know for both the system as I am learning ClearCase and finding difficulty to learn it as there are very less tutorial for CC as compare to svn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ClearCase, you would define a config spec which would:

- select all versions at the right tag
- create a new branch for any new versions created from that starting point.

That would give a view with:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../myBranchFromv1/LATEST
element * /main/0 -mkbranch myBranchFromv1
element * 00.00.01
element * /main/LATEST
```

(Even if you don't have a label, you can create a [config spec starting from a certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578525/6309))

---

In SVN, that would [simply be a `svn copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11298005/6309).

```
svn copy your.repo.URL/tag/00.00.01 your.repo.URL/branches/myBranchFromv1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell where I can learn ClearCase and ClearQuest  better as I didn't find any good tutorial where I can learn it.

Comment: @R.Sha for ClearCase, my answers here on Stack Overflow (read the first 3 or 4 of this list: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a6309%20%5Bclearcase%5D%20is%3aanswer) are enough to get you going. But you also fid good introduction video on the Youtube IBM channel, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRXKBhVdVrU.

Comment: ..Just one word from heart. Thank You. Your solution really helps me. Thanks Stackoverflow for providing me the platform to interact with best adviser.

Comment: @R.Sha you are most welcome. All you need to do now is to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.

Comment: @R.Sha it depends on the version of ClearQuest you are interesting in, but http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/dw-r-cccq-evalguide/ is a good start.

Comment: Do you mind if I want to ask some more concern/issues on clearcase ? I need to understand some concept and finding your answer well understandable and accurate.

Comment: Sure, as long as it is a separate question, for me or other to answer to.

Comment: Thanks but is there  any way to PM you ?

Comment: Not if your questions can be asked here on Stack Overflow. I participate on this Q/A website *precisely* to avoid PM.

Comment: @R.Sha that being said, if you have FireFox 36: https://hello.firefox.com/jjcUFB14eDg (for a quick chat)

Comment: thanks for being so coperative and i tried the same but it requires - "Firefox Hello requires access to your camera and microphone". I think there is no typing option there.

Comment: @R.Sha no you can choose to not share your camera